# Find supremum and infimum of $\{\arctan n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I want to find supremum and infimum of $\{\arctan n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ and decide if maximum and minimum exist. I think I have found supremum and infimum but how do I determine if max and min exist?

Since $\arctan$ is growing $n=1$ should be infimum and $n=\infty$ should be supremum, therefore I got $\sup=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\inf=\frac{\pi}{4}$. But is there a maximum and a minimum?

How I reason: If I remember correctly, the function $\arctan x$ does not have a maximum or minimum, but since we have the lowest value $n = 1$ here, infimum could also be a minimum? But since it is growing and moving towards infinity, it has no maximum.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The sequence is strictly increasing, so it clearly has no maximum, and the first element is a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\arctan(a)+\arctan(1/a)
=\pi/2
$
when
$a > 0$,
$\arctan(n)
=\pi/2-\arctan(1/n)
\to \pi/2
$
as
$n \to \infty$
and
$\arctan(n)
\lt \pi/2
$
for all $n$.